# slim dynamic conditional class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Just to help other developers, because there is no similar question on SO.

```
div class=(is_active? ? 'active' : 'inactive')
div class=('active' if is_active?)
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

See the examples below:

```
div class=(is_active? ? 'active' : 'inactive')
div class=('active' if is_active?)
```

The same approach can be used to assign dynamic values to other attributes.

Comment: How would you do that for multiple conditions?

Comment: See below in the comments to your answer.

Comment: This can also append a class, such as:  `div.councilor class=(councilor.retired? ? "retired" : "")`  generates: `div.councilor.retired`

Answer (score 23):

I use array of classes and nil element if there is no need to include class in list, then compact array to remove nil elements and finally join all together.

```
div class=(["cday", "col-md-1", day.day == 1 ? "col-md-offset-#{day.cwday-1}" : nil].compact.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have multiple conditions I am doing right now something like

```
div class=(('foo ' if is_foo?) + ('bar' if is_bar?))
```

Though I feel it to be a blemish if is_bar? return false and the generated HTML results in

```
<div class="foo "></div>
```

(the blemish is the blank character after the `foo`). If someone had a solution for that would be awesome.

Comment: Try `String#rstrip` in this case with 2 conditions:  
`div class=((('foo ' if is_foo?) + ('bar' if is_bar?)).rstrip)`.
Or `div class=([('foo' if is_foo?), ('bar' if is_bar?)].compact.join(' '))` for several conditions.