# conditionally have css tag inline in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a set of css tags like this:

```
.card.hidden.small.u-margin-bottom-1
```

I'd like to conditionally show the `.hidden` tag while maintaining this style of syntax (I have seen this [slim dynamic conditional class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242170/slim-dynamic-conditional-class) and don't want to change style).

Could I do something like?

```
.card(.hidden if true_statement).small.u-margin-bottom-1
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.card.small.u-margin-bottom-1 class=(:hidden if true_statement)
```

for more classes:

```
.card.small.u-margin-bottom-1 class=('class-1 class-2' if true_statement)
```